# Is it possible to send contact info via SMS to an arbitrary cellphone?

Tags: mobile, sms, contacts, vcf-vcard

I am working on an app to send data to customers via sms.  What I'd like to be able to do is send a welcome sms to a customer that includes my contact info in a format that can just be "click to add", for lack of a better term.

If there's no way to do this that will work across phone platforms, are there resources that show how to do it for the most common cell phones?

Comment: umm... I don't think the cell tag means what you think it does, although it is an interesting use.

Comment: @yoda, I think you're [right](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk).   Although I have to say to actual meaning of that tag doesn't seem real useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send an initial welcome SMS to introduce yourself and then send a subsequent message with your contact details as a VCARD.

You can send contact details via SMS as a VCARD and most mobile phones will be able decode that and add it to their address book simply.

At least if you sent an introductory text first they'd be expecting their phone would prompt them to save a new contact? Customers receiving a new contact might delete it if they didn't know someone was going to send it to them.